# Switch function

Tags: r, switch-statement, return

I need check the value ranges for a dataframe, each vector in data frame has different ranges. The data frame need to be checked might be different each time.
All the features I have are `c("temp","y","d","p")`. I want to check if the value of each vector are within the range, otherwise fill in `NA`.

```
temp_range = c(0,140)
y_range   = c(0,100)
d_range = c(-80,100)
p_range = c(0.00,99.9)

check_range <- function(x, range){
  x[which(x<range[1] | x>range[2])] = NA
  return(x)
}

check_all_range <- function(pp, features){
  for( ff in features){
    z<- switch(ff,"temp"   =  check_range(pp$temp,temp_range),
                  "y"    =  check_range(pp$r, y_range),
                  "d" =  check_range(pp$d, d_range),
                  "p"= check_range(pp$p, p_range),           
    )
    print(f)
    return(z)
  }  
 }
```

Now I have a data frame

```
x=data.frame(c(200,30,20,-10,-140), c(-10,20,100,10, NA))
   names(x)=c("temp","y").  
   features = c("temp","y")
```

When use `check_all_range(x,features)` somehow it only check the first feature `temp` and `x` is still unchanged.
I think maybe I didn't understand switch well.

Comment: The `return` in `check_all_range` is inside the `for` loop, therefore the function returns during the first iteration. There are other problems too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are overwriting z each iteration of the loop.

if you prepopulate z with pp and then you only assign z[ff] to be the checked values it should work

**new code for check_all_range**

```
check_all_range <- function(pp, features){
  z <- pp
  for( ff in features){
    z[ff] <- switch(ff, 
                "temp" =  check_range(pp$temp,temp_range),
                "y"    =  check_range(pp$y, y_range),
                "d"    =  check_range(pp$d, d_range),
                "p"    =  check_range(pp$p, p_range),           
    )
    print(ff)
  }  
  return(z)
}
```